# set css background doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(function () {
    var getBg = $('.one').css('background');
    $('.two').css('background', getBg);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohvuLqwe/)

Worked well in Chrome, doesn't work in IE and FF, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation on `.css( propertyName )`:

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., `margin`, `background`,
>   `border`), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.

It looks like in Firefox using `window.getComputedStyle( element )`, which I believe is used by jQuery under the hood to get `.css('property')`[1], returns a `CSS2Properties` collection where the `background` property is an empty string. But all the more specific background-related properties (like `background-image`, `background-position` etc) are fine. It's probably the same for other shorthand properties, for example `font` is an empty string while `font-family`, `font-size` etc. have values.

You can fix it by cloning these properties one by one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ohvuLqwe/5/

```
$(function () {
    // get a reference to original element
    var original = document.querySelector('.one'); 
    // get the computed style
    var styleprops = getComputedStyle( original );
    // create an object to hold the relevant properties
    var clonebg = {};
    // iterate over the computed properties...
    for( var prop in styleprops ){
        // and store them in the object if they are not empty and the name starts with "background"
        if( prop.indexOf('background') == 0 && styleprops[prop] != "" ){
             clonebg[ prop ] =  styleprops[prop];
        }
    }
    // use the jQuery .css({}) method to set all the cloned properties.
    $('.two').css(clonebg );
});
```

[1] https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/var/getStyles.js

Answer (score 1):

Use 'background-image' to get the image

```
$(function () {
    var getBg = $('.one').css('background-image');
     $('.two').css('background-image', getBg);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/ohvuLqwe/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `background-image` property

```
$(function () {
    var getBg = $('.one').css('background-image');
    alert(getBg)
    $('.two').css('background-image', getBg);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohvuLqwe/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
var getBg = $('.one').css('background-image');
$('.two').css('background-image', getBg);
});
```